How can I turn off reactor HTTP logging on an Azure Function app
How can I turn off reactor HTTP logging on an Azure Function app?
I added a KeyVault SecretClient class instance , which is creating thousands and thousands of logs around reactor.http.
This host.json config doesn't seem to work.  I still get Information logging from reactor.  Here is log example:
Severity level: Information, Message: 18:40:19.040 [reactor-http-epoll-5] 
  [INFO ]   - : Client is not on azure vm

And here is the config that I last tried:
"logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "None",
      "Host": "Warning",
      "Function": "None",
      "Azure": "Error",
      "Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets": "None",
      "Azure.Core.Http": "Error",
      "Azure.Storage.Blob": "Warning",
      "reactor": "None",
      "reactor.netty": "None",
      "reactor.netty.http": "None",
      "reactor.netty.http.client": "None",
      "reactor.netty.http.server": "None",
      "reactor.netty.transport": "None",
      "reactor.netty.channel": "None",
      "reactor.netty.resources": "None"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond" : 20,
        "excludedTypes": ""
      }
    }
  }


Add logging.level.reactor= OFF, logging.level.reactor.netty =  OFF , logging.level.reactor.netty.http = OFF in applications.properties.
